# Custom Django Model User

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I can't serialize this class :

```py
class RidesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    passageiros = CarregaDadosPassageirosSerializer(many=True, required=False,read_only=True)
    passageiros_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=False, queryset=User.objects.all(),source='passageiros')
    class Meta:
        model = Ride
        fields = ['motorista','passageiros','passageiros_id','data_publicaçao',
                  'data_saida','origem','destino','preço','veiculo','modalidade']
```

which brings this other class , `CarregaDadosPassageirosSaerializer`, and I need to extend a field to the model User :

```py
class CarregaDadosPassageirosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        diretorio = serializers.ImageField(source='user.profile.diretorio',read_only=True)  
        nome_usuario = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        model = User
        fields = ['id','username','email','diretorio']

        def get_nome_usuario(self, obj):
            return obj.nome.username
```

The error in the output i've been receiving every time is the following :
`Field name 'diretorio' is not valid for model 'User'`. So, how can I fix this ?

I've tried changing some aspects in models.accounts:

`user = mo.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile', on_delete=mo.CASCADE)`

Comment: Can you show your `User` model?

Comment: Arun T, I'm using the usual User model. I´ve tried customizing a diferent one to see if it was possible to extend the field i needed, but failed anyway . Here it is the new user model :
class CustomUser(mo.Model):
    user = mo.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=mo.CASCADE,related_name='customuser')
    diretorio = mo.ImageField(blank=False,upload_to=upload_path)
    username = mo.CharField(max_length=50)
    email =mo.EmailField(max_length=50)